# badRequest: Invalid requests[0]: No request set. (Google::Apis::ClientError)

Tags: ruby, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

I can't solve this problem. Can someone help me?

Issue: badRequest: Invalid requests[0]: No request set. (Google::Apis::ClientError)

I just need to include formulas in a cell sequence.

Here is the code:

````
  requests: [
    {
      repeatCell: {
        range: {
          sheetId: sheet_id,
          startRowIndex: 0,
          endRowIndex: 10,
          startColumnIndex: 1,
          endColumnIndex: 6
        },
        cell: {
          userEnteredValue: {
              formulaValue: "=FLOOR(A1*PI())"
          }
        },
        fields: "*"
      }
    }
  ]
}

response = service.batch_update_spreadsheet(spreadsheet_id, request) ```
````

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, although I cannot see your whole script in your question, it is found that in your request body, you use the camel case. I think that this is the reason of your issue. In the case of Ruby, please use the snake case as follows.

#### Modified script:

```
request = {
  requests: [{repeat_cell: {
    range: {
      sheet_id: 0,
      start_row_index: 0,
      end_row_index: 10,
      start_column_index: 1,
      end_column_index: 6
    },
    cell: {
      user_entered_value: {
          formula_value: "=FLOOR(A1*PI())"
      }
    },
    fields: "*"
  }}]
}
response = service.batch_update_spreadsheet(spreadsheet_id, request, {})
```

#### Note:

- In this modification, it supposes that your `service` can be used for using the batchUpdate method of Sheets API to the Google Spreadsheet of `spreadsheet_id`. Please be careful this.